# MySQL order_by CAST in Fuel Framework

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, fuelphp

Im working on Fuel Framework and I need to build query with `order_by title` which is `varchar` but most of them are numeric. 
I need to sort it in true numeric order.

So I want to use `"CAST(title as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC"`.

Problem is in Fuel ORM.
I cant see in docs any information about CAST in `order_by`.

Do you know what I trying to say? :D
Can you help me?

Comment: Try using `DB::expr()` instead of plain string. http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/classes/database/db.html#/method_expr

Not sure if it will work, since as far as I know, it doesn't respect table aliases.

Comment: Works!Thx, Barta.

For those who read this my query looks like this:
`$dat['photos'] = Model_Photo::find('all', array('where' => array('gallery_id' => $id), 'expr' => 'CAST(title as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC'));`

Comment: then it's an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DB::expr()` instead of plain string.

http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/classes/database/db.html#/method_expr